# как отсортировать двумерный ассоциативный массив в алфавитном порядке по одному из значений

Tags: php

Необходимо отсортировать в алфавитном порядке по значению [FIO] несколько ассоциативных двумерных массивов

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 180
            [id_day] => 3
            [id_shift] => 1
            [pupil_id] => 99
            [code_change] => 1
            [FIO] => Солдатов Ваня
            [phone] => ##
            [FIO_parent] => ##
            [age] => ###
            [id_teacher] => 1
            [name_teacher] => Наталья
            [tax] => 250
            [new_tax] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [id_day] => 3
            [id_shift] => 1
            [pupil_id] => 7
            [code_change] => 1
            [FIO] => Ерослаева Кира
            [phone] => ##
            [FIO_parent] => ##
            [age] => ###
            [id_teacher] => 1
            [name_teacher] => Наталья
            [tax] => 250
            [new_tax] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [id_day] => 3
            [id_shift] => 1
            [pupil_id] => 4
            [code_change] => 1
            [FIO] => Теплова Саша
            [phone] => ##
            [FIO_parent] => ##
            [age] => ###
            [id_teacher] => 1
            [name_teacher] => Наталья
            [tax] => 250
            [new_tax] => 
        )
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 701
            [id_day] => 3
            [id_shift] => 2
            [pupil_id] => 311
            [code_change] => 1
            [FIO] => Трофимов Захар
            [phone] => 
            [FIO_parent] => 
            [age] => 
            [id_teacher] => 6
            [name_teacher] => Мери Хачатрян
            [tax] => 200
            [new_tax] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 463
            [id_day] => 3
            [id_shift] => 2
            [pupil_id] => 232
            [code_change] => 1
            [FIO] => Сибгатулин Роберт
            [phone] => ирпо
            [FIO_parent] => тол
            [age] => ьлд
            [id_teacher] => 7
            [name_teacher] => Елена Лебедева
            [tax] => 250
            [new_tax] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 461
            [id_day] => 3
            [id_shift] => 2
            [pupil_id] => 231
            [code_change] => 1
            [FIO] => Елисеев Гриша
            [phone] => иро
            [FIO_parent] => тол
            [age] => ьол
            [id_teacher] => 7
            [name_teacher] => Елена Лебедева
            [tax] => 250
            [new_tax] => 
        )
)
```

Comment: на ваш выбор есть `uasort()`, `uksort()`, `usort()`. Выбирайте более подходящую под вашу задачу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = [
    ['FIO' => 'Солдатов Ваня'], ['FIO' => 'Ерослаева Кира'],
    ['FIO' => 'Теплова Саша'], ['FIO' => 'Трофимов Захар'],
    ['FIO' => 'Сибгатулин Роберт'], ['FIO' => 'Елисеев Гриша']
];

uasort($array, function($a, $b){
    return $a['FIO'] <=> $b['FIO'];
});

print_r($array);
```

Comment: спасибо, работает!